# A snippet after every image

Tags: functions, loop

folks.

I need to put a piece of code after every post image (post attached image).
it's something like this:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3079" src="imgurl.jpg" alt="02" width="2592" height="1936">
<div>some piece of code here</div>
```

It will be a share button to share the image instead the post, so every image will need a custom code to share the image url.

There's a way to do this?

Comment: So this is not an image caption? What did you try so far? What if the image is wrapped in some HTML tags? Is it a static snippet?  What about using e.g.  jQuery?. Is this restricted to the post content? Please update the question with more info, thanks.

Comment: This gonna be a dinamic code, jQuery didn't worked like I wanted, I will make a share button to share the image instead the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [get_image_tag](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/media.php#L369) filter:

```
add_filter('get_image_tag', function($html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size)
{
    return $html . '<div>some piece of code here</div>';
}, 10, 6);
```

**References**:

- [get_image_tag()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_image_tag/#source-code)
- [get_image_send_to_editor()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_image_send_to_editor/)
- [wp_ajax_send_attachment_to_editor()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ajax_send_attachment_to_editor/)

Comment: I use get_image_tag filter and it's work. Thanks @dan!